# Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 22985

Tags: java, android, webview

I know there are a lot of questions about this problem but it doesn't seem to be answered really. I am loading an html page from a webservice into a webview and then I want to go to another activity when I push a button in the list in the html page. But when I do so, the webview goes blank and I get this error:
Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 22985.
What should I do?

```
package com.myapp.tabbar;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.text.style.RelativeSizeSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
    private TextView text;
    private WebView webView;
    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.month);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablayout_id);
        appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout)findViewById(R.id.appbarid);

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);


        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date c = cal.getTime();
        for(int i =0;i<7;i++)
        {
            String day = "" + android.text.format.DateFormat.format("EEEE", c);
            String day1 = (String) DateFormat.format("dd", c);
            String monthString = (String) DateFormat.format("MMM", c);
            String year = (String) DateFormat.format("yyyy", c);
            String MonthYear = monthString.toUpperCase()+","+year;
            String day2 = day.substring(0, Math.min(day.length(), 3));
            SpannableStringBuilder str1 = new SpannableStringBuilder(day2);
            SpannableStringBuilder str = new SpannableStringBuilder(day1);
            str1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(R.color.temp), 0, day2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            str1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.4f), 0, day2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            str.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, day1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            text.setText(MonthYear);
            SpannableStringBuilder temp = new SpannableStringBuilder(str1+"\n"+str);
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(temp));
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            c = cal.getTime();

        }
        Fetch_data fetch_data = new Fetch_data();
        fetch_data.execute();
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
            {
                Fetch_data fetch_data = new Fetch_data();
                fetch_data.execute();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

//        webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
//            @Override
//            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
//                openActivity2("30");
//                return false;
//            }
//        });
    }
    public void openActivity2(String url)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Id",url);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    class Fetch_data extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        String htmlcontent = "";
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.wtf("onPreExecute","onPreExecute");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HashMap<String, String> nameValuePairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
            int i = tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition();
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date c = cal.getTime();
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, i);
            c = cal.getTime();
            String modifiedDate= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(c);
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            c = cal.getTime();
            String modifiedDate1= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(c);
            nameValuePairs.put("categoryId","1");
            nameValuePairs.put("fromDate",modifiedDate);
            nameValuePairs.put("toDate",modifiedDate1);
            String req;
            try {
                req = ConnectionRequests.POST("http://www.idsdemo.me/champsservice/generalservices.asmx/GetSchedule", nameValuePairs);

                JSONObject JO = new JSONObject(req);
                htmlcontent = JO.getString("ScheduleHTML");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.wtf("ERROR FOUND : get_all_data req"," e : "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                return null;
            }
            return htmlcontent;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            webView.loadData(result, "text/html", null);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            Log.wtf("url","----");
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                boolean timeout = true;
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                    Log.wtf("url", url);
                    openActivity2(url);
                    return true;
                }
                @Override
                public void onPageCommitVisible(WebView view, String url)
                {
                    super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url);
                }
                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(final WebView view, final String url, Bitmap favicon)
                {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
                {
                    timeout = false;
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: any Html Page redirect form web development side donot waste your time....

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: have u write web page?